# http load testing tool

Tags: http, load-testing

I want to record web activity as would be done by a single user and then run one or multiple such simulteanous users (perhaps tweaking some params, such as converting `user/password` into `user1/password`, ..., `usern`/`password`).
Playing with timing would be nice too.

Comment: You may find the answers to this Stack Overflow question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459/website-load-testing

Comment: windows or unit?
Do you allready use Microsoft dev tools
What lanaguages are you happy to program in?
What is the skill set of the person that is going to use the tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My company, BrowserMob, provides a [low-cost load testing service](http://browsermob.com/load-testing) that might work well for you. You can sign up for a [free trial](https://browsermob.com/free-stress-test), upload a Selenium script, and then further modify the script to use different logins, etc. The entire script ends up written with a  [JavaScript API](http://static.browsermob.com/api), so you can do some pretty advanced things. You can $100 worth of free testing, which can go a long ways, especially if you use our Virtual Users feature rather than our Real Browser Users feature.

Comment: great company Patrick - I like the idea very much. note to self: check this more thoroughly later.

Comment: This is receiving spam flags. You might want to read [Limit to self-promotion in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers) and scale it down a bit.

Comment: IMO this is not spam.  The commercial interest of the poster is clearly stated, and the OP obviously found it helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) is one of the best I have used, the tool is built in java but I used this to test my ASP.NET application. Tested using 3 machines. (each machine would only simulate a max of 1000 users at one time). We ended up doing the load test for 3000 concurrent users.

Answer (score 1):

[ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is a nice simeple way to start.

Comment: it's not a piece of cake to upload a file

Answer (score 0):

I work on a project that may fit the bill. It's called [engulf](http://engulf-project.org). If you need to generate a lot of load engulf works pretty well because it supports multiple workers. It also has a real-time web interface, which  is pretty enjoyable to watch IMHO.